# How to project (or paste)panorama to model?

Tags: three.js, webgl, uv-mapping

Before question,I seached many places, I find some similar idea but without my solution.And my question can be also described as how to recalculate the model's uv to fix the panorama designed for six faces skybox.

Recently,I came upon a unique way to get fluent 3D roaming experience on matterport's Official network https://matterport.com/gallery/

I just want to know how did they do that?Their product is very fluent when swich the panorama picture.

After I roaming many times,I found the secret. I realized that the panorama carrier they use is not box or sphere,but is the object they show first!The evidence is that when switch the point,the object such as chair and table would have their own shadow(one chair have two image one stand up and the other one lie on the floor

[image]

With the object in panorama paste on their own correspond object and with depth information the roaming switch become more fluent (As for why they do not use the object directly ,I think because of the limited hardware,Many irregularity faces which get from scanning equipment cannot be use directly

[image]

And I want to use this idea in my project ,I have a group of six panorama which can paste on a boxGeometry perfectly,and I just want to paste them on model.but I stuck in project 360 degree.Yes I just find how to project one direction but I cannot project the remaining five.

```
var _p=BufferGeometry.attributes;
for (var i = 0; i < _p.position.count; i++){
    var uvtempbeforeconvert= ( new THREE.Vector3(_p.position.array[3*i],_p.position.array[3*i+1],_p.position.array[3*i+2]) ).clone().applyMatrix4(houseObject.matrixWorld).project(camera1)
//use the worldvertices to get its screen coordinate            
    if(uvtempbeforeconvert.x<1&&uvtempbeforeconvert.x>-1 && uvtempbeforeconvert.y<1 &&uvtempbeforeconvert.y>-1)      {
VerticesArray1.push(_p.position.array[3*i],_p.position.array[3*i+1],_p.position.array[3*i+2]);uvArray1.push(uvtempbeforeconvert.x*0.5+0.5,uvtempbeforeconvert.y*0.5+0.5);
```

Yes,I success in calculating one direction.BUT I cant deal with the triangle faces which **occupy two more** view frustum,like a face at the edge of the box.

How should I deal with  this problem?Or I run in the **FALSE** direction **at first**?Which direction should i run in ?

Answer (score 0):

After asking many people,I just find that I need to usd shadermaterial in threejs ,and use a function named cubetexture,samplercube.With that I can get the pixel color what I need!